# Hide component changing its state redux react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I've created a component which I'm trying to change it's state when clicking a button but I don't know why I'm not receiving this change... 
My component uses a `Button` that it's another component, so what I need is when I click to this `Button` is to change the state of the `PopUp` component (the one I want to hide) and remove it from the UI.

This is my `Button` component but I can not change it nor modify it... so I should modify the new one

```
const MyButton = connect(
  undefined,
  (dispatch, { name, surname, arguments: args = [] }) => ({
    onClick: () => dispatch(myButton(name, surname, args)),
  }),
)(Button)

export default MyButton
```

So and reducer is

```
export const MY_BUTTON = "MY_BUTTON"
export const myButton = (name, surname, args) => ({
  type: MY_BUTTON,
  name,
  surname,
  arguments: args,
})
```

Ok, and now the PopUp component that I want to do is :

```
export default class PopUp extends React.Component {
  state = { hidden: false }

  handleClick = value => {
    this.setState({ hidden: true })
  }

  render() {
    let { name } = this.props
    if (this.state.hidden) {
      return null
    }

    return (
      <div className="modal-wrapper">
        <div className="modal">
          SomeText
          <br />
          <MyButton
            name={name}
            surname="example1"
            arguments={["yes"]}
            onClick={() => this.handleClick("yes")}
          >
            [ Yes ]
          </MyButton>{" "}
          <MyButton
            name={name}
            surname="example2"
            arguments={["no"]}
            onClick={() => this.handleClick("no")}
          >
            [ No ]
          </MyButton>{" "}
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

so why it's not dismissing the popup when I click on Yes or No?

I'm creating this `Component` as follows :

```
{showPopUp && <PopUp name={name} />}
```

One guy told me that I could create an onClick inside a div and inside that div create the buttons so I detect two onClick, is that possible?

Comment: where you are declaring 'showPopUp' variable

Comment: thing you named "reducer" is actually action creator. do you have reducer that reacts on action and transforms store? also you `<MyButton ... onClick={this.handleClick}`> is useless and is never called because `onClick` prop is later overwritten in `MyButton` code(where you can `connect()`)

Comment: @ShivaKumarN showPopUp is working and is showing the component when it should, so forget about this please, the component that I have is not hiding when clicking the button yes nor no

Comment: @skyboyer yes... that's what I'm doing wrong... how do I detect when MyButton is clicked just remove PopUp component?

Comment: try wrapping your MyButton in a div and set onClick on that div

Comment: @h-des could yout post an answer to do that please? if it works I'll mark your answer as a correct one

Comment: @skyboyer the answer given will happen the same thing you told right? it will overwritten right?....

Comment: now check it i have modified for simple hide

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide component just Try this:

```
export default class PopUp extends React.Component {
  state = { 
     hidden: false,
  }

handleClick = () => {
 this.setState({ 
   hidden: true,
 })
}
render() {
  const { name } = this.props;
  const { hidden } = this.state;

 return (
  <div className="modal-wrapper">
  { !hidden  && 
    <div className="modal">
      SomeText
      <br />
      <MyButton
        name={name}
        surname="example1"
        arguments={["yes"]}
        onClick={() => this.handleClick}
      >
        [ Yes ]
      </MyButton>{" "}

      <MyButton
        name={name}
        surname="example2"
        arguments={["no"]}
        onClick={() => this.handleClick}
      >
      [ No ]
      </MyButton>{" "}
    </div>
  }
  </div>
)
}
}
```

And onthing try refactor dispatcher like this:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  dispathMethod: (name, surname, args) => dispatch(name, surname, args)), 
})

//if you are using selector use it:

const mapStateToProps = createStructuredSelector({
  accessories: selectSomething(),
});


const withConnect = connect(
 //here(1st param)if selecter using put ? mapStateToProps : null 
  mapDispatchToProps,
);

export default compose(
  null,
  withConnect,
)(Button);
```

Comment: But it will show the 2 divs and text, right? I just want to show nothing if buttons are clicked

Comment: And it will happens the same stuff that skyboyer said : also you <MyButton ... onClick={this.handleClick}> is useless and is never called because onClick prop is later overwritten in MyButton code(where you can connect())  right?

Comment: look, you need this `hidden` to be in props rather state. or you popup will be unable to be open again.

Comment: yes just he wants to hide once click any yes/no button

Comment: @ShivaKumarN yes but I want to show it again, it's like a accept or cancel popup not only once shown...

Comment: @ShivaKumarN Is not hidding anything :(

Comment: @skyboyer what do you mean? can you provide an example please?